# What does this security.yml mean?

Tags: php, symfony

I have got a symfony security.yml file

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    providers:
        in_memory:
            users:
                ryan:  { password: ryanpass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
                admin: { password: kitten, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

I wanted some eleborations concerning this file..

1. Can I have my own firewall settings like I replace secured_area by some othername?
2. What is the difference between pattern and path ?
3. If I access the url "myhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/admin" , what is supposed to happen ?
4. Do I need a path /admin in my controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I have my own firewall settings like I replace secured_area by some othername?

Yes, you can have your own firewall(s).

> What is the difference between pattern and path ?

Pattern is for firewall, path - for access control. Both are defined in the same way

> If I access the url "myhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/admin" , what is supposed to happen ?

You will be redirected to login form

> Do I need a path /admin in my controller ?

All routes that match pattern will be enriched with security token. This is not necessary to be only `/admin`, it can also be `/admin/somepage`

I recommend you to read [security chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) from Symfony2 documentation.